# Jackson Filter and Polymorphism

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, jackson, polymorphism

I've got an abstract class **Vehicle**:

```
@JsonFilter('Vehicle_Filter')
public abstract class Vehicle {
    private String brand;
    private int nbOfWheels;
    //Other attributes, constructor & methods
}
```

I've got one child class **Car** extending Vehicle:

```
@JsonFilter('Car_Filter')
public class Car extends Vehicle {
    private int nbOfDoors;
    private boolean isElectric;
    //Other attributes, constructor & methods
}
```

And I've got one other child class **Bike** extending Vehicle:

```
@JsonFilter('Bike_Filter')
public class Bike extends Vehicle {
    private double tirePressure;
    private boolean isAllTerrain;
    //Other attributes, constructor & methods
}
```

Let's say that I have a class **VehicleCollection** representing a list of Vehicles I would want to display in a HTML page:

```
@JsonFilter('VehicleCollection_Filter')
public abstract class VehicleCollection {
    private List<Vehicle> vehicles;
    //Other attributes, constructor & methods
}
```

For that, I will serialize it using *Jackson* (from *fasterXML*). 
Let's say that I want to display only some of the attributes for each vehicle. I will use a *FilterProvider* interface.

The question is : when I want to filter a vehicle's attribute, I don't want to distinguish wether it's a Bike or a Car. All that matters, is that it's a Vehicle. I thought I could come up with that when filtering:

```
FilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider()
            .addFilter("VehicleCollection_Filter", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("vehicles"))
            .addFilter("Vehicle_Filter", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("brand", "nbOfDoors", "isElectric"));
```

... But when calling the *writer*, this error is thrown : `Could not find filter with id: 'Car_Filter'`. It seems that Jackson does not want to hear about polymorphism...

Has anyone had the same issue ? If yes, can I have a hint on how to overcome it ? And if no, is there some documentation or some implicit explanation about why can't Jackson filters deal with inheritance ?

Comment: If All that matters, is that it's a Vehicle why do you have `@JsonFilter('Car_Filter')`? and `@JsonFilter('Bike_Filter')`?

Comment: Because in other parts of the application, I need to display Cars and Bikes separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the error you are getting is because when Jackson serializes a `Car` instance it sees a `@JsonFilter` annotation on the class and expects to find a filter with given id through the filter provider.

Ways to solve:

1. Add `.setFailOnUnknownId(false);` that will eliminate the error but cause all fields to be serialized.
2. Add a default filter `.setDefaultFilter(filterOutAllExcept("brand", "nbOfDoors", "isElectric"))` that will be applied when `"Bike_Filter"` and `"Car_Filter"` cannot be found. That will get the required output, but with  limited flexibility. You get 1 default filter for all classes per filter provider and 1 filter per class for all filter providers. You can't annotate a class with 3 filters and pick one of them in a provider for example.
3. Use `@JsonView` instead. Unlike filters, views themselves support (multiple) inheritance and you can specify more than 1 per field/getter which offers great flexibility. E.g.:

   ```
   abstract class Vehicle {
       @JsonView(Detail.Basic.class)
       private String brand;
       @JsonView(Detail.Standard.class)
       private int nbOfWheels;
   }

   class Car extends Vehicle {
       @JsonView(Detail.FullCar.class)
       private int nbOfDoors;
       // multiple views on a field
       @JsonView({Detail.Standard.class, Detail.Type.class})
       private boolean electric;
   }

   class Bike extends Vehicle {
       @JsonView(Detail.FullBike.class)
       private int tirePressure;
       @JsonView({Detail.Standard.class, Detail.Type.class})
       private boolean allTerrain;
   }

   class Detail {
       // marker interfaces never implemented
       interface Basic {}
       interface Type {}
       interface Standard extends Basic {}
       interface FullCar extends Basic {}
       interface FullBike extends Basic {}
       // 1 view can inherit from many
       interface Full extends FullCar, FullBike {}
   }

   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   // only 1 view per writer
   ObjectWriter basicWriter = mapper.writerWithView(Detail.Basic.class);
   ObjectWriter standardWriter = mapper.writerWithView(Detail.Standard.class);
   ObjectWriter typeWriter = mapper.writerWithView(Detail.Type.class);
   ```

Views are also less error prone as the match types instead of strings i.e. if you have a typo in a view name, your IDE will highlight it. With `@JsonFilter` ids you get runtime errors.

I guess the fact that the term *"sub-class"* is mentioned in `@JsonView` [docs](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView.html) but not in `@JsonFilter` [docs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFilter.html) is as good an explanation as you can get for the observed behaviour.

Comment: I tried all solutions, and all of them work !
I have a preference for the one using the Views, as it is way more OO, more Java ;) And also, for people who hate writing plain Strings, that's really a relief ! Thx !